# How can I get HTML element when importing Vue via CDN?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, cdn

I'm using Vue 3.0.2 in my project, loaded via CDN as follows:

```
<head>
 ...
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.2"></script>
</head>
```

How can I access an HTML element in my Vue component when importing the library via CDN? I want to do the equivelant of what would be `document.getElementById('element')` in plain JS.

Related posts on here suggest that calling `$this.el.querySelector` should work for this, however I don't have access to that function. I suspect due to importing Vue via CDN?

My component looks as follows...

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
        data() {
            return {
                // data members.
            }
        },
        methods: {
            // method definitions.
        } });

app.mount('#app')
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: you can use `document.getElementById` if you so wish, vue doesn't remove access to document, or you can put a `ref="element"` on the element and access like `this.$refs.element` though if you properly use data or add models for state you can do most things without needing to access or manipulate the DOM manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.2"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <h1>{{ data }}</h1>
      <input type="text" ref="input">
      <button @click="log">LOG</button>
    </div>
    <script>
      const app = Vue.createApp({
        data() {
          return {
            data: 'any'
          }
        },
        methods: {
          log() {
            console.log(this.$refs.input.value)
          }
        }
      });

      app.mount('#app')
    </script>
```